# Meteor publish subscribe wrong output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, publish, subscribe

im new to Nodejs / Meteor and Mongodb. im having this problem which i cannot get my data when i try to use publish and subscribe in meteor

lib/collection.js

```
Reports = new Meteor.Collection('reports');
```

lib/routes.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('dashboard', {
    path: '/dashboard',
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('reports-limit', {limit: 5});
    },
    data: {
      title:'Dashboard',
      reports: function(){
        console.log(Reports.find({}));
        return Reports.find({});
      }
    },
    action: function () {
      if (this.ready()) {
        this.render();
      }
    }
  }); //end this.route
});//end Router map
```

server/publisher.js

```
Meteor.publish('reports-limit', function(option){
  var limit = options.limit;
  return Meteor.reports.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: limit});
});
```

client/template/dashboard.html

```
<Template name="dashboard">
  <div class="content">
    {{title}}
    <ul>
      {{#each reports}}
        <li>{{_id}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</Template>
```

I don't get any display in the id and the console.log() is giving me

```
L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: M…o.Matcher, skip: undefined…}
```

as a result

this is the packages i installed

```
$ meteor list
accounts-facebook                     1.0.4  Login service for Facebook accounts
bootstrap                             1.0.1  Front-end framework from Twitter
iron:router                           1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform                       1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation  1.0.1  Expose mongodb aggregation framework (mapReduce, aggregate and distinct), to SERVER si...
service-configuration                 1.0.4  Manage the configuration for third-party services
```

i'm not sure what i've been missing and what i've done wrong.

Comment: It's `waitOn`, not `onWait` And it needs to return a subscription: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option

Comment: Actually, a lot of your code is wrong. I would highly suggest giving the Iron Router guide a read - https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md and also follow along in the Discover Meteor Book - https://www.discovermeteor.com/

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny thanks, updated my code i looks like it haven't solve my problem. it still give me the same result

Comment: Like I said, you have a large number of errors in your code. I suggest going slowly through some tutorials to really understand what's going on.

Comment: You're also using `console.log` on a Meteor cursor and I think you're expecting an array of documents, instead. It should be `console.log(Reports.find({}).fetch());` in this case.

Comment: @akshat thanks. this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you name a collection with a global variable, e.g. `Reports = new Meteor.Collection('reports');`, you should use that global to access the collection both server and client side.

So `return Meteor.reports.find();` in your publication is wrong. It should read:

```
return Reports.find();
```

The rest of the query looks ok.